# knockout.js and fixed left scrolling binding on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, knockout.js

I have this binding that goes on about 60+ rows.  When I scroll left the lag is kind of slow and jumpy.  Anyway to fix this or make it smoother?

```
<!-- ko foreach: Times -->
                    <tr class="time-games">
                        <td class="time-container" data-bind="fixedLeft: { }">
                            <div class="time">
                            </div>

    ko.bindingHandlers.fixedLeft = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

            var leftOffset = parseInt($(element).css('left'));

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                $(element).css({
                    'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + leftOffset 
                });
            });
        }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
$(element).css({
    transform: "translate3d(" + ($(this).scrollLeft() + leftOffset) + "px,0,0)"
});
```

jQuery > 1.9 will auto-fill the vendor prefixes for you depending on which browser is being used.  Translate3d usually out-performs just setting the left property.  You'll have to change your `parseInt($(element).css('left'))` to `$(element).offset().left` as well, to account for the lack of `left` css.

In addition, you can throttle the function (underscore.js provides a nice way of doing this) in order to keep performance the same even if many events are fired very quickly.  You could use css3 animations to make up for the loss in accuracy in between each function call if it ends up looking choppy.

Comment: Cool Ill try it out.  Ill wait for anyone else to respond before giving you a answer check.

Comment: Only give the check if it works!  If not let me know, I can try to give other suggestions.

Comment: This works pretty well, still a delay and jump, but the choppiness has decreasted.  Going to mark this as the answer and keep this functionality for a while.